# Using Jquery to check if a URL is valid

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

A long running background process creates a text file to indicate the completion of the process. From the frontend, I'd need to check every few seconds if the text file has been created or not.

I am doing this check from `http://DomainA.com` However the file is created in `http://DomainB.com/Mytext.txt`

Can someone help me write a jquery script that checks for a file across domain?

PS: Currently, I am doing a ajax postback that executes a `WebMethod` in ASP.NET that creates `HttpWebRequest`. This works functionally, but I have major performance problems. So, I need a light weight way of finding if a URL is valid or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using YQL with JQuery that lets me do cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a server-side script on your own server which pings the URL (using cURL or whatever) and responds with a JSONified version of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Do not fire `HttpWebRequest` at the moment the jQuery script requests it. Run `HttpWebRequest` independently at same intervals in some background thread which in turn sets some shared boolean toggle. Finally let the code which should respond to jQuery requests return the state of this toggle (thus without firing the `HttpWebRequest` itself).

Comment: If the performance bottleneck is due to HttpWebRequest, I am not sure how triggering it separately would make any difference. Let me know if I have'nt understood your answer correctly.

Comment: So that the jQuery doesn't have to wait until `HttpWebRequest` finishes. It should just grab the "last known" result.

Comment: Do you think that JQuery waiting for the HttpWebRequest is the one that's causing the exceptions? In the event viewer, I see timeout exceptions.

Comment: No, it's the `HttpWebRequest` itself which takes so long. Just fire it in intervals in a background thread and let it set a commonly accessible variable which jQuery just have to request at its own intervals.

Answer (score -1):

call it using jQuery ajax, then look at the result if it is 404? This is asynchronous though, so you need to use javascript continuations if you are in a workflow

Comment: Cross-domain *AJAX* requests are blocked by browsers.

Comment: You can not do cross-domain requests via XHR.